# Update nested object by reference

Tags: javascript, mutable

Consider this example:

[image: example 1]

This is expected behavior to me, as soon as we change the object value, the `originalObj` gets mutated as well.

Now consider this example (nested object):

[image: example 2]

As you can see, **the object has not been updated**.

Even the other way around doesn't work (updating the original object doesn't mutate the reference):

[image]

Why is this happening, and how can I circumvent it?

Comment: Objects are pass by reference - objects properties (unless the property value is another object) wont be passed by reference.

Comment: @tymeJV Well, it's copied by value really.  It's just that the value in the first case happens to be a reference to an object.  In the second case, it's just a number.

Comment: Please replace images with formatted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, things are passed around by value.  In your initial code:

```
var ref = originalObj;
```

The *value* of `originalObj` has been copied to `ref`.  That value is a *reference* to an object, so both variables have independent copies of that reference, but they both reference the same underlying object.  Changes in the object are reflected in both variables.

In this:

```
var fooRef = originalObj.foo;
```

Again, the value of `originalObj.foo` is being copied, but this time that value is just a number, `1`.  At this point, the variable and the property have independent copies of that value, but it's just a number, not a reference to an object.  Changes in either of these are not reflect in the other.

> how can I circumvent it?

By using your first block of code - you need a reference to the object containing the property you wish to update - you're unable to update a variable or property directly by keeping a reference/pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no reference to primitive type, the value is being copied.
If you need a reference, wrap this value inside an object and point to the object